# storing value by reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Js but I understand that there's no such concept as there is Pointers in other languages. But what if, let's say, I wanna do this:

```
// an object's property
removeItem: function(item_id) {
   var obj = this.panel.items[item_id]; // panel is some other property
   delete obj; // but it won't delete that object
   delete this.panel.items[item_id]; //however, this will
}
```

I wanna understand, how? And, how can I pass `this.panel.items[item_id]` as reference to `obj` so it would actually delete the main object.

Does `obj` holds reference or clone of `this.panel.items[item_id]`

Comment: [`The JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object; if no more references to the same property are held, it is eventually released automatically.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: Pass `this.panel.items` and `item_id` separately, then `removeItem: function(obj, id) { delete obj[id] }`. `delete` can work on `this.panel.items[item_id]` because it is not a function but a special syntax, and it doesn't evaluate its arguments like a function would. The special syntax `delete a[b]` deletes property `b` from `a`; once you evaluate `a[b]` (as in `removeItem(a[b])` would), then you can't know it is a value in a property of `a`.

Comment: Does `obj` holds reference or clone of `this.panel.items[item_id]`

Comment: A reference. All variables in JS hold references (except for primitive values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because obj isn't a property of an object, it's an object itself. delete operator removes a property from object. You should read this 
[delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)
So.. if you want to work with obj, you could do something like this

```
removeItem: function(item_id) {
   var obj = this.panel;
   delete obj.items[item_id];
}
```

Comment: `var obj = this.panel.items; delete obj[item_id]` works as well.

Comment: i understand now. that was a stupid question. I should've thought that one through